# how to use Spring-Integration Kafka InboundGateway and OutboundGateway with a MessageConverter?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

1. My goal:

process #1:
a) send a Guava ListMultimap collection to Kafka OutboundGateway, have the gateway convert it on-the-fly to a Json string.
b) receive the answer from process #2 as a Json string and have the OutboundGateway convert it back on-the-fly to a ListMultimap

process #2:
a) receive a Json string message from process #1 through Kafka InboundGateway, have the InboundGateway convert it on the fly to a ListMultimap
b) send back a ListMultimap answer to process #1 and have the InboundGateway convert it back on-the-fly to a json string.

2. What I've tried (pseudo-code; sorry, can't provide full source-code I'm afraid):

```
#process1

RecordMessageConverter converter = new StringJsonMessageConverter(
                                       .JsonMapper.builder()
                                       .addModule(new GuavaModule)
                                       .build());

ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String,Object,Object> template = 
    new ReplyingKafkatemplate<String,Object,Object>(producerFactory,replyListenerContainer);
template.setMessageConverter(converter); //conversion for submission ?

IntegrationFlow flow = 
    IntegrationFlows.from(
        () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(someListMultimap).build(),
        c -> c.poller(Pollers.cron(cronSchedule)))
        .handle(
            Kafka.outboundGateway(template)
                .replyMessageConverter(converter) //conversion for reception ?
                .topic(gatewayTopic)
        .channel(outputChannel)
        .get();

#process2

RecordMessageConverter converter = new StringJsonMessageConverter(
                                       .JsonMapper.builder()
                                       .addModule(new GuavaModule)
                                       .build());
IntegrationFlows.from(
    Kafka.inboundGateway(consumerFactory,containerProperties, producerFactory)
        .messageConverter(converter) //conversion for reception ?
        .configureTemplate(t -> t.messageConverter(converter))) //conversion for submission ?
    .transform(ListMultimap p -> ListMultimap.of("newkey","newvalue2","newkey","newvalue2"))
    .get()
```

3. What problem I have:

when the message is sent from process #1, I get the following error (sorry, can't provide full callstack):
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableListmap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.google.collect.ImmutableListMultimap is in unnamed module of loader 'app';...
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28)

4. Background for this request:

I have a 2nd messaging library (other than Kafka), and I want to abstract inside the inbound/outbound gateway itself how the payload is converted during transport to another process, with the application core-processing only having to deal with ListMultimaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template's message converter is bypassed because the gateway creates a `ProducerRecord` directly.

Here is a work around:

```java
    @Bean
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> kpmh(StringJsonMessageConverter converter,
            ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> repTemplate) {

        KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler = Kafka.outboundGateway(repTemplate)
                        .replyMessageConverter(converter)
                        .topic("so68770130").get();

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        ProducerRecordCreator creator = (message, topic, partition, timestamp, key, value, headers) -> {
            ProducerRecord temp = converter.fromMessage(message, "so68770130");
            return new ProducerRecord(topic, partition, timestamp, key, temp.value(), headers);
        };
        handler.setProducerRecordCreator(creator);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(StringJsonMessageConverter converter,
            ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> repTemplate,
            KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> kpmh) {

        return f -> f.handle(kpmh)
                .log();
    }
```

I opened an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3617

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback Gary !   
Just for your information, the Kafka OutboundChannelAdapter (on top of above-mentioned Kafka OutboundGateway) also seems to suffer from the same problem.

Comment: One more thing in the code example above is that, even if I provide to StringJsonMessageConverter a custom JsonMapper instance with extra modules like Guava , the parent class (JsonMessageConverter) will internally instantiate a DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper whose TypeFactory is the default jackson one, which does *not* contain the extra modules. End result is that guava collections are recognized as simple types instead of map-like types leading to deserialization failure (I ended up writing a "CustomJackson2JavaTypeMapper" to pass the custom TypeFactory corresponding to my custom JsonMapper)

Comment: Yes, they both use the same message handler. Please open a GitHub issue for the mapper problem.